# Shell Script - What does this date expression mean

Tags: linux, shell, date

I'm trying to figure out what this expression means

```
expr \`date "+%j"\` % 2
```

I know it looks at the day of the year (example today 034) but what does the 
`\' % 2` do?

Comment: It can be used to implement something that run every second day.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use the `$()`-syntax than the backticks, it's clearer and more flexible:

```
expr $(date +%j) % 2
```

outputs 0 and returns false when the day of the year is even, outputs 1 and returns true when it's odd. `%` is the `expr` modulo operator.

```
echo $((10#$(date +%j) % 2))
```

is an almost equivalent command which does not call the external `expr` command. The difference is that using `echo` you get always true as return code; the outputs are identical. `10#` is needed because otherwise a string beginning with `0` (like today's `034`) would be interpreted as an octal number.